# Play with color, noiseDetail(), and the rate at which xoff and yoff are incremented to achieve different visual effects

Tags: canvas, p5.js, noise

Hi Everyone im trying to solve the Exercise 8 of the Nature of Code Book and did some coding but i dont know how to implement many perlin noise as a combination
this is my code:

```
var inc = 0.2;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1280,720)
  pixelDensity(1);
  var yoff = 0;
  loadPixels();
  for (var y = 0; y < height; y++){
    xoff = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      var index = (x + y * width) * 4;
      var r = noise(xoff, yoff) * 255;
      pixels[index+0] = xoff;
      pixels[index+1] = r;
      pixels[index+2] = yoff;
      pixels[index+3] = 255;
      xoff += inc;
      }
    yoff += inc;
  }
  updatePixels();
  noLoop();
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I get a pic but I don't know where to implement the many Noises
Thanks in advance

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCsOi.png![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCsOi.png!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzymz.jpg)

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: The output must be like the second pic I added to the topic with different visual effects and colours

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the increment and multiply the `xoff` and `yoff` by something for the coloring. I wasn't able to recreate the image you want but I made some changes you might like.
example:

```
var inc = 0.01;
var zoff = 0;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(600,600)
  pixelDensity(1);
}

function draw() {
  createCanvas(600,600)
  pixelDensity(1);
  var yoff = 0;
  loadPixels();
  for (var y = 0; y < height; y++){
    xoff = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      var index = (x + y * width) * 4;
      var r = noise(xoff, yoff, zoff) * 255;
      pixels[index+0] = xoff*50;
      pixels[index+1] = r;
      pixels[index+2] = yoff*50;
      pixels[index+3] = 255;
      xoff += inc;
      }
    yoff += inc;
  }
  zoff += inc*2;
  updatePixels();
  //noLoop();
}
```

Comment: It came very near to the desired muster but another question is it possible to implement besides X and Y the variables I and j to get the final result as the picture ?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I meant how can i implement it if i add two for loops of i and j like: for(var i = 0; i < d; i++) and for(var j = 0; j < d; j++) into the two former loops